Why parent process execute twice on using python3 os.fork() on ARM MacOS?
I'm  trying to run a Flask server and a client that makes requests to it simultaneously.
When I run the following code:
def main():
    """
    Start a local server and call it
    using parallel processes. 
    """

    pid = os.fork()

    if pid == 0:
        # GET data
        get()
        return 0

    else:
        # Run the server
        run()
        return 0

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

with the cmd:
python main.py <SOME_ARGS>

I get the following output:
 * Serving Flask app 'server.server'         < ---- Server Starts running
 * Debug mode: on
Traceback (most recent call last):           < ---- Client runs, Error Traceback
.
.
.
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=3000): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x100919640>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused'))

 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:3000.         < ---- Server finishes running

   Hello, World!                             < ---- Client runs again, this time successfully 

The Issue is that I expect the parent process to run once, but it seems to run twice.

I suggest you take a look at the multiprocessing module rather than trying to manage a fork

@SIGHUP I did something like p = Process(target=run), p.start(), p.join(), sleep(), get(). I still get an error :
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 121, in spawn_main
parent_sentinel = os.dup(pipe_handle)

Forking should work but Flask in debug mode might be doing something weird behind the scenes.

@nneonneo Actually fork did work. writing this program, I tried a few different solutions. But fork() led to too many unexpected behaviours. IDK if it's the apple silicon chip or the MacOs.
But I used fork anyway, here's the code : https://github.com/ma-habibi/Backend-Projects/blob/main/Caching%20Proxy/main.py

Use threading: Instead of forking, you can use threading to run the Flask server and the client in parallel.
import threading
from flask import Flask
import requests
import time

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return "Hello, World!"

def run():
    app.run(port=3000, use_reloader=False) 

def get():
    time.sleep(1)  
    response = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:3000')
    print(response.text)

def main():
    server_thread = threading.Thread(target=run)
    server_thread.start()
    get()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


I get the following error:
Exception in thread Thread-1 (run):
Traceback (most recent call last):
.
.
.
handler = _signal.signal(_enum_to_int(signalnum), _enum_to_int(handler))
ValueError: signal only works in main thread of the main interpreter

I edited the log, try it now
